# convert date format to 'YYYYMMDD'

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, I have date string as shown below:

```
var dateStr = "Wed Mar 25 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
```

I need to convert it to  "YYYYMMDD" format. For example the above date should be : `"20150325"`

Comment: So, what is the problem? What part of [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) causes difficulties?

Comment: how you are getting this `"Wed Mar 25 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"`? by using `new Date()` or something else?

Comment: from custom calendar component not by using new Date(0. It coming as a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good function for doing that which I found and used it always.

```
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
var mm = this.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth() is zero-based
var dd = this.getDate();
return [this.getFullYear(),
(mm>9 ? '' : '0') + mm,
(dd>9 ? '' : '0') + dd
].join('');
};
var date = new Date();
date.yyyymmdd();
```

Comment: He has a date string

Comment: He can convert the datestring to this format and use it to get the date var d = new Date("2015-03-25T12:00:00-06:30");

Comment: in general, it's a bad idea to modify/extend the built-in objects prototype

Answer (score 4):

Here's a dirty hack to get you started. There are numerous ways of achieving the format you want. I went for string manipulation (which isn't the best performance).

```js
var someDate = new Date("Wed Mar 25 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
var dateFormated = someDate.toISOString().substr(0,10).replace(/-/g,"");
    
alert(dateFormated);
```

Comment: You could use `.replace(/-/g,"")` once instead of two `.replace("-","")`. Also there's a snippet tool (Ctrl-M) for JavaScript (and more) so everyone can run your code and see the result by themselves :)

Comment: @Rafalon Thanks for that, didn't know about Ctrl+M :). Corrected my answer.

Comment: You're welcome :) I find this feature really nice and I think it deserves to be used more. Also `console.log` is less aggressive to me than the `alert` pop-up, but it only is my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

```
function getFormattedDate(date) {
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  var month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();
  month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;

  var day = date.getDate().toString();
  day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;

  return year + month + day;
}
```

And then just call the function :

```
alert(getFormattedDate(new Date());
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Date` object is able to parse dates as string `d = new Date( dateStr );` provided that they are properly formatted like the example in your question.

The `Date` object also offers methods to extract from the instance the year, month and day.

It's **[well documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)** and there are plenty of examples if you just Google for it.

---

What is worth mentioning is that the `Date` object **doesn't handle timezone** and the internal date-time is always converted into the client's timezone.

For example here's what I get if I try to parse your date in my browser (I'm in GMT+01):

```
dateStr = "Wed Mar 25 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
d = new Date( dateStr );

---> Wed Mar 25 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) = $2
```

If you need to handle timezone properly the easiest way is to use a library like **[MomentJS](https://momentjs.com)**

Comment: Here is the reason why this is a good answer. Because he already knows how to join some data but he needs to get right data. and this explains exactly that. stackoverflow people should stop solving problems just answering question is fine