# Date format not getting updated (YYYYMMDD) when assigned back to object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, momentjs

I wanted a simple YYYYMMDD format so that I could display it on an angular frontend.

Here, after the manipulation is done on the date object, i want to assign it back to the `TIMESTAMP` column in the result object. `TIMESTAMP` is set as Date object in the database (postgres). The TIMESTAMP column still retains the `-` separator when assigned `newDatex`.

I have even tried using momentjs but to no avail.

I have looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943012/convert-date-format-to-yyyymmdd) but it doesn't help resolve my problem. I don't want the format to be updated in the database. I need it updated so that I can send an updated format `(YYYYMMDD)` to my frontend.

```
app.get('/api/:date', (req, res) => {
    var date = req.params.date;

    Model.findAll({
        where: {
            TIMESTAMP: {
                [Op.eq]: date
            }
        },
        order: [
            ['SYMBOL', 'ASC']
        ]
    }).then( result => {

        if (result != undefined){

            let i = 0;


            let year = new Date(result[i].TIMESTAMP)


            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                if(result[i].TIMESTAMP != undefined){
                    let date = year.getDate().toString()
                    let month = (year.getMonth() + 1).toString()
                    let newyear = year.getFullYear().toString();
                    (date.length == 1) && ( date = '0' + date);
                    (month.length == 1) && (month = '0' + month);

                    let newDatex = new String();
                    newDatex = newyear + month + date;
                    console.log('modified date:', newDatex)
                    moment(result[i].TIMESTAMP).format("YYYYMMDD");

                    result[i].TIMESTAMP = new String();
                    result[i].TIMESTAMP = newDatex;

                    console.log('should be removing  "-" but isn\'t: ',result[i].TIMESTAMP)
                }
            }
            res.json(result)

        }
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I input the date into a new Date() constructor any way and formatted like this

```
var d = new Date('05 October 2011 14:48 UTC');
var day = d.getUTCDate();
var month = d.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var year = d.getFullYear();

// Check day for length to format
if (day.length < 2) {day = '0' + day};
console.log(`${year}${month}${day}`);
```

Then got this:

[image]

Also hopefully you didn't take the answer in the post you referenced, that person is modifying the prototype chain of a built-in object which is a **huge** no-no.

Let me know if this works for you.

*Also*, if your data type is "Date" in Postgres and not something like varchar it might be automatically formatting the record for you when you store it. So you might have to change the data type or reformat the data every time you pull it.

Comment: Hi, the date manipulation is fine. The separator `-` gets added only when i  try to assign it to result[i].TIMESTAMP. The TIMESTAMP column in the database does have a `date` type though and I don't want to touch the database at this point.